# different ways of extracting columns from data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I've seen people use a couple of different ways of pulling a single column out of a `data.frame` in R:

```
df[,1]
df$colname
```

and:

```
df[[1]]
```

I have tend to use the latter recently, but just thought that these may be doing different things.  What are the differences between these, and why would one prefer one over the other?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you studied `help("[")` and `help("[.data.frame")`?

Comment: Yes, a few times…  I should have stated that I'm only considering the case of a *single* column, I know that `[[` only works with single values.  Will update my question.

Comment: "[[" only returns single values where value might include vectors of length greater than 1, but it can accept (single) vectors of length greater than 1 (up to the maximum "dimension" of the recursive object (2 in the case of a data.frame).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "[[" version does not allow selection of more than 1 element (although that single element might be an atomic vector of length greater than 1 or a list of arbitrary complexity, while the "[ , j]" version would allow multiple items to be returned. If offered a vector of length more than 2 the "[[" form will attempt to extract the element from recursive application of "[[" to successive elements of first the column result and then the item in that vector. (...since an "element" might be a multi-valued vector.) This is a bit like an array extraction.

```
test <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=letters[1:5], c=setNames(1:5, letters[1:5]) )
# also would give same results for data.frame
test[[3]]
#1 2 3 4 5 
test[[c(1,3)]]
#[1] 3
# In this case the same as:
test[3,1]
#[1] 3
```

The "[[" version (as noted by the help page) will drop names from a vector, but that is tangential to this question, since data.frames don't let you keep names anyway.

The most important difference is between "[[" and "$", because "[[" lets you use a computed index.

The other major distinction is between what is returned by `obj[1]` and `obj[[1]]`. The first returns a list, the second returns a vector (at least when `obj` is a list.)

Comment: Yes, I knew about the difference between single/vs elements between the two—but didn't make that clear, have updated the question.  Forgot about the `[[` vs `$`, are they the same except that you have to use a symbol with `$`?

Comment: your last edit uses a `list` and not a `data.frame`.  I'm aware of why I'd want to use `[[` here, in fact this was what caused me to learn of the `[[` operator and their distinction!

Comment: `obj[['token']]` is the same as `obj$token`. But if you wrote `obj[[token]]`, then the evaluator would look for the value of `token` and substitute it as the argument to `[[`. You will get the same result in that example if you substitute `data.frame` for `list`.

Comment: I don't think I've ever noticed that passing a vector to `[[` will do different things with recursive objects like lists.  I have been mainly using `[[` in order to get R to complain when my code is used incorrectly—i.e. when a vector is passed rather than a vector.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like @DWin and @B.Mr.W covered the most common ways to extract columns from a data frame using `[` and `[[`.

As an alternative to `[` or `[[` methods, you can also use the base function, `subset`, to extract columns from a data frame.

For example, `subset(mtcars, select=mpg)` will extract the column named `mpg` from the `mtcars` data set. Or, if you want multiple columns, you can include a vector of column names, such as `subset(mtcars, select=c(mpg, cyl))`. Note that you do not need to quote the column names when using the `subset` function.

You can also get the columns by their index in the same way: `subset(mtcars, select=1)` selects the first column in the data frame, and is the same as `subset(mtcars, select=mpg)`.

While this may not be used when simply selecting columns, the `subset` function can lead to more immediately understandable and verbose code, and is useful when also extracting some rows of interest, e.g. `subset(mtcars, subset=hp<100, select=c(mpg, cyl))`. You can also do this using `[`, but it isn't as elegant, e.g. `mtcars[mtcars$hp<100, c("mpg", "cyl")]`.

Comment: The downside of using `subset` is that is only designed for interactive use. There are warnings on its help page against using it in programming situations.